# React js useCallback caching and refs as dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Does useCallback hook cache only the function reference or does it also cache the values/result of the function itself? Also does using a ref in a dependency array really produce any effect, for example, component refs? If not, then is there any way to ensure a change in ref value has a proper effect?

I thought only the function reference would be cached but after reading an article that states that useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps), I am not sure if it's actually the case. Moreover, I tried using component refs as dependencies (like [Video.js](https://videojs.com/guides/react/#react-functional-component-and-) and [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/example/previous-next-methods)) but I don't think it has much of an impact compared to other dependencies.

Comment: "[...] is there any way to ensure a change in ref value has a proper effect?": why are you using a ref if you need to React to react to state change? Why can't you use state? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: "useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)": the `fn` inside `useMemo` isn't being called (compare: `() => fn`, `() => fn()`), therefore the function is being cached and not the result.

Comment: Refs to components as stated in Video.js and react-slick documentation

Comment: So the useCallback hook will have no effect on the result or values used inside the function defined, only on the function referential equality?

Comment: The documentation you've linked is telling me you're trying some sort of solution however I still don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. How is your ref changing? When it changes what effect should it have? This question has symptoms of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/); also see the link there regarding "asking smart questions".

Comment: `useCallback` will have no effect on the result of the function passed to it or the values used by the function. Are you seeing some effect? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I already properly stated my problems. I wanted to know if using a ref in a dependency array produces any effect and if not, then is there any way to ensure a change in ref has a proper effect i.e. if ref.current updates. As well as I wanted to know if useCallback hook cache only the function reference or does it also cache the values/result of the function.

Comment: The documentations are just examples of where I have applied refs to components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea the purpose of `useCallback` is to allow the function to maintain it's reference between renders unless a dependency you specified has change.

If for example you have a function `f(x,y)=>x+y` you can use callback with an empty dep array `useCallback((x,y)=>x+y,[])` and the function will never change. It will always give consistent behaviour since it only uses it's arguments to resolve outputs. But if you had another function `h` and another external value `z` that is subject changes, and h defined as `h(x,y)=>x+y+z`, then you would need to include `z` in the dependencies so that if `z` were to change, the function returned from `useCallback` would have a new reference.

So the uses for `useCallback` are generally so that when you pass the function around it doesn't for example trigger rerenders of children or a common thing I think is when using the function as a dependency in child component's `useEffect` declarations. So not useful if the operation inside the function is expensive, then you should separately memoize the result.

About the ref thing, don't think it does anything to include ref in the dependency, think it's just like having the array empty. Maybe eventually if the ref was stored in a state could be useful but not really sure.

Here's a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wwyw9f?file=src%2FApp.tsx) with some examples maybe useful.

Can paste it too if it may get deleted.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  //x and y to be used as function arguments
  const [x, setX] = React.useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = React.useState(0);

  //z is variable also used in function calculation but not as an argument
  const [z, setZ] = React.useState(0);

  const ref = React.useRef<number>(0);

  //counter to see how many times function updates
  //will start at 2 cause strict mode but that's no issue really
  const [i, setI] = React.useState(0);

  //function to add x and y from args and add z from state
  const fn = React.useCallback(
    (x: number, y: number) => {
      // console.log(`${x}+${y}`);
      return x + y + z;
    },
    [z] // if you remove z and update it get wrong result
  );

  //update fn count on fn change
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setI((i) => i + 1);
  }, [fn]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('nice');
    return () => console.log('ref cleanup');
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ x, y, z })}</pre>
      <button onClick={() => setX((x) => x + 1)}> x ++</button>
      <button onClick={() => setY((y) => y + 1)}> y ++</button>
      <button onClick={() => setZ((z) => z + 1)}> z ++</button>

      <pre>x+y+z={fn(x, y)}</pre>

      <pre>fnCount:{i}</pre>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          ref.current = ref.current++;
        }}
      >
        ref++
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Many documentation uses ref in the dependency array for their components, so I was wondering if there actually was any effect. So, not including z in the dependency array of useCallback will give the wrong result i.e. will only use its initial value?

Comment: I think for the ref it's included because strictly speaking including the ref object itself may be more correct, but not even really.. I think it's the same for most cases. It's like adding a constant to the array. So it can be there, what should not be there is `ref.current`. Even that functionally won't change anything but it's just confusing for no reason. Same with ref object. Doesn't matter too much

Comment: Yea thats right, you can check in the example linked, if you are using some external (not function argument) variables in the body of the function, and its not in deps, and it changes, it will give the wrong result. This is because what's being called is actually referencing the function that was produced previously. In that example yea its the initial function.